# How to filter nested query in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario:

- `Game` has `GameUID, GameName`
- `Player` has `PlayerUID, PlayerName`
- `GamePlayer` has `GamePlayerUID, GameUID, PlayerUID, FinishedPosition`

I need to return back one row of a join between these three tables for each Game row where the return row contains the Player row with the lowest finished position.

Example,

**Game**

```
{some guid}, Game 1
{some guid}, Game 2
{some guid}, Game 3
```

**Player**

```
{some guid}, Player 1
{some guid}, Player 2
```

**GamePlayer**

```
{some guid}, {game 1 guid}, {player 1 guid}, 1
{some guid}, {game 1 guid}, {player 2 guid}, 2
{some guid}, {game 2 guid}, {player 1 guid}, 2
{some guid}, {game 2 guid}, {player 2 guid}, 1
```

My expected result would be

```
Result
-------
{game 1 guid}, Game 1, {player 1 guid}, Player 1
{game 2 guid}, Game 2, {player 2 guid}, Player 2
```

Now my instincts tell me that this should be the query:

```
select G.GameUID, G.GameName, V.PlayerUID, P.PlayerName
from Game G inner join (
    select top(1) GameUID, PlayerUID 
    from GamePlayer GP
    where GP.GameUID = G.GameUID
    order by FinishedPosition asc) as V on V.GameUID = G.GameUID
inner join Player P on V.PlayerUID = P.PlayerUID
```

Now, the problem with this query is that `where GP.GameUID = G.GameUID` results in a

> multi-part identifier "G.GameUID" could not be bound

error.

If I exclude that and rely only on the join criteria, the subquery ALWAYS has the same first row and so it only joins one of the games.

I hope I've made this clear enough for someone to offer an answer.

BTW, this is being put in a View.  I do not want to write a stored proc to do this unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select G.GameUID, G.GameName, P.PlayerUID, P.PlayerName
from Game G inner join (
    select GameUID, MIN(FinishedPosition) as FinishedPosition
    from GamePlayer GP
    group by GP.GameUID) as V on V.GameUID = G.GameUID
inner join GamePlayer GP2 on (GP2.FinishedPosition = V.FinishedPosition and GP2.GameUID = V.GameUID)
inner join Player P on (P.PlayerUID = GP2.PlayerUID)
```

Whew. I think that does it? Let me know if it fails.